# How to hide LOGO using CSS code in Qualtrics Survey?

Tags: css, qualtrics

I want to hide my company LOGO from the last page of survey using CSS in LOOK & FEEL of Qualtrics Survey. I'm using the below code:

```
#Logo{display: none;}
```

This code hides the LOGO from all the pages of the survey. Is there a way to modify this code to hide the LOGO just from the last page of my survey.

This is how the look & feel of Qualtrics looks like:

[image: Look & Feel Page in Qualtrics]

Comment: Is your project in react js ?

Comment: No.. I use Qualtrics-which is a SaaS survey tool. I'm not from coding background, so not very good at it. Most of the features are out of box and doesn't require any custom coding.

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate last page from other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the CSS that hides the logo from the Look & Feel Custom CSS.  Add the following to the question text of a question on the last page of the survey in HTML View:

```
<style>#Logo{display: none;}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a class next to logo in the last page, like this:

```
<div id="logo" class="last-page" >...</div>
```

and in your css add **display: none** just to this page like this:

```
.last-page { display: none; }
```

or:

```
.last-page { visibility: hidden }
```

**visibility: hidden** hide the logo but consume the space

Comment: This is not working.. I don't have an option to view LOGO page. Here is a link to see what exactly qualtrics is as this is not a common survey tool - https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/look-feel/look-feel-overview/

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique ID, e.g. `last`, in your HTML such that you can target it using CSS like so:

```
<div id="logo last">Content</div>
```

Then, target the `last` id in your CSS:

```
#last{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: This is not working.. I don't have an option to view LOGO page. Here is a link to see what exactly qualtrics is as this is not a common survey tool - https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/look-feel/look-feel-overview/

Comment: `id`  cannot have spaces ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name)) not can have multiple ids. Did you mean a `class` attribute?